# Why does my in.read(); function inconsistently only when positioned after a bin.readLine(), even though both have consistent input?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, inputstream, outputstream

So I've been having some real problems with a multi-client server application I've been coding. After lots of fiddling around I came to realise that although an in.read() method that I'd positioned after a bin.readLine usually receives its information, occationally it just hangs as though the information had never been sent. This is even though all information has been sent in exactly the same way in the same order. To simplify things I just wrote a very simple client server program to test this situation.

Both the client and the server use while (true){ to loop continually, and both have System.out.println(here1) or (here2) etc. to allow me to see where in the code any unexpected behavior has arisen. So this is the while loop on the client side. The in.read(); at the bottom of the loop is only there to block until the server's while loop also reaches the bottom, so that the client doesn't loop faster than the server.

```
while (true){
    System.out.println("here1");

pout.println("Hello everybody");

    System.out.println("here2");

out.write(150);

    System.out.println("here3");

in.read();
}
```

And this is the server's while loop.

```
while (true){
    System.out.println("here1");

String a = bin.readLine();

    System.out.println("here2");

int b = in.read();

    System.out.println("here3");

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);

out.write(1);
}
```

Some when I run the applictions, everything behaves as expected, both looping round and printing a continually repeating list of here1..2..3. And on the server side here1..2..3. followed by Hello Everybody, 150. However all of a sudden after a second or two (sometimes less, sometimes more - it's very inconsistent) the server blocks just after here2, and so it seems that it is waiting for read() to receive information. However on the client side you can see that everything was sent as normal and the client is waiting just after here3.

I don't understand this at all, particularly the inconsistency. If I replace pout.println() with out.write(), and replace bin.readLine() with in.read(), this problem never happens and the two programs loop around forever like no ones business. I would really like to know why this happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffered reader 'bin' is buffering data that you are trying to read via 'in'. You can't do that: you can't mix buffered and unbuffered I outnumber the same underlying source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's just that in the book, Learning Java (O'Reilly), in an example the Inputstream is used to create a BufferedReader, and the program uses both in.read(), bin.readLine(). If one shouldn't mix the two what is the correct way if you want a program to receive both lines of text as well as single bytes? I have however just noticed in the example in the book, the in.read() comes just before the bin.readLine() and when i re-arrange the above code to replicate this it works perfectly. Is this the correct way of mixing them or is it still dangerous?

Comment: The book is wrong. This technique cannot work in general, only when all the direct reads precede all the buffered reads. You need to redesign your protocol.